# Second order differential equation Cauchy problem.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following Cauchy problem

\begin{cases} y''(t) = \frac{(y'(t))^2 - 2}{2t y'(t)} \\y(1) = 4 \\ y'(1) = 1 \end{cases}

I proceed by setting $v(t) = y'(y^{-1}(t)) $ to obtain the system 
\begin{cases} v'(t) = \frac{(v(t))^2 - 2}{2t (v(t))^2} \\v(4) = 1  \end{cases}

This is solvable by separations of variables, I obtain

$$\int_1^{v(t)} \frac{s^2}{s^2 -2} ds= \int_4^t ds /2s  $$

I note that $\frac{s^2}{s^2 -2} = 1+ \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2} -2} - \frac{1}{s\sqrt{2} +2}$

And so I remain with $$v(t) - 1 +\frac{\ln(\sqrt{2}v(t)-2)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\ln(\sqrt{2}-2)}{\sqrt{2}} -\frac{\ln(\sqrt{2}v(t)+2)}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\ln(\sqrt{2}+2)}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\ln(t)}{2}- \frac{\ln(4)}{2}$$

Where I can't seem to explicit out $v(t)$. How to proceed?

I know the problem is solvable and the solution is $y(t) = - 2/3(2-t)^{3/2} + 14/3$.

Comment: why so complicated? Set $v=y'^2-2$, then $v'/v=1/t$.

Comment: @LutzL thanks for this nice method. It did not occur to me, still I would like to find the mistake in how I proceeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tricked yourself by relabelling the variable on which $v$ depends, which should rightfully be called $y$, with $v(y)=y'(t(y))$, as $t$, which makes it difficult to keep track of which $t$ is which. The $t$ in the denominator in the expression for $y''$ is the argument of $y$, whereas in the denominator in the expression for $v'$ it's the argument of $v$; but you proceeded as if they were the same. I don't see how to express $t$ in terms of $y$ and $y'$, so I doubt you can make this approach work by correcting the error.

I wonder, though, why you don't just apply separation of variables directly to the original equation, integrating

$$
\int\frac{y'}{y'^2-2}\frac{\mathrm dy'}{\mathrm dt}\mathrm dt=\int\frac1{2t}\mathrm dt\;?
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer I understand where I fooled myself in the notation. Using the method you describe don't I run into the same problem of having an explicit solution for $y'$ given that the equation above is the same equation I had ?

Comment: @Monolite: It isn't; there's no square in the numerator.